# Safari OnUnload event on user exit

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, safari

I am calling a JavaScript function from the code behind by adding it the the OnUnload event, because I need it to fire when the user exits the window or navigates to a new page.

```
bodyName.Attributes.Add("OnUnload", "JSFucntionName");
```

This function is firing on all browsers when a user refreshes or navigates to a new page, and it is firing on IE, Chrome, and Firefox when a user exits, but not on Safari.

Does Safari not call the `OnUnload` event when the user exits the window? Or is there a work-around for calling a JavaScript function in Safari on a user exit?

Comment: Some actions are not allowed during unload phase in some browsers [HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#changes-2011-05-25). ("The showModalDialog(), alert(), confirm() and prompt() methods are now allowed to do nothing during pagehide, beforeunload and unload events."), sometimes the event is omitted because in modern WebKit the [PageCache](https://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/) might be used. Can you set up a test page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling onpagehide instead as a workaround, I believe it is called when the the page is closed as well:

```
window.onpagehide = function() {
    // some code here.
};
```